# Parsing JSON data with C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, json

I have about 7000 lines of JSON data that I want to parse. An example of just part of it can be seen [here](https://graph.facebook.com/367501354973?access_token=2227470867|2.fYhXYnFbw5vb6GXNpTzHkw__.3600.1288994400-506939663|Wjtw41UvZctwiQEW3GYEETTALZI). What I did was use `WebRequest` and `StreamReader` to put all the data into a string. (Oddly, it puts all of the data into one VERY long line). But now I want to parse this and I am not sure how. Can anyone explain how to use `Deserialize`? I have parsed JSON data with Java before but I am having trouble doing so with C# especially with my inability to find documentation with clear examples. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905807/mapping-tool-for-converting-javas-json-to-from-c

Comment: http://json.org -- good clean fun with links

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try [JSON.Net](http://json.codeplex.com), if you have not seen this it should help you.

> Json.NET library makes working with
>   JSON formatted data in .NET simple.
>   Key features include a flexible JSON
>   serializer to for quickly converting
>   .NET classes to JSON and back again,
>   and LINQ to JSON for reading and
>   writing JSON.

Deserialization discussed [here](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help).

> The quickest method of converting
>   between JSON text and a .NET object is
>   using the JsonSerializer. The
>   JsonSerializer converts .NET objects
>   into their JSON equivalent and back
>   again.

The basic code structure for deserialization is below - `Target` still needs to be filled out to capture the rest of the parsed data items with the appropriate type.  The file mentioned `json.txt` contains your data from the URL above.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class NameAndId
{
    public string name;
    public int id; 
}

public class Data
{
    public NameAndId[] data;
}

public class Target
{
    public string id;
    public NameAndId from;
    public Data likes;
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\temp\json.txt");
        Target newTarget = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Target>(json);
    }
}
```

Here is the first part of the JSON stream for reference:

```
{
   "id": "367501354973",
   "from": {
      "name": "Bret Taylor",
      "id": "220439"
   },
   "message": "Pigs run from our house in fear. Tonight, I am wrapping the pork tenderloin in bacon and putting pancetta in the corn.",
   "updated_time": "2010-03-06T02:57:48+0000",
   "likes": {
      "data": [
         {
            "id": "29906278",
            "name": "Ross Miller"
         },
         {
            "id": "732777462",
            "name": "Surjit Padham"
         },
```

Comment: Could you please give me an example on how to use it with the link I provided?

Comment: @Daisama - I will take a look, but that won't be happening very quickly.

Comment: @Daisama - take a look, seems straightforward.

Comment: Wow, this is very helpful. Thank you. So for the ones with multiple entries ("likes" and "messages"), then I should just make an array of objects?

Comment: It looks to me like "likes" and "messages" can all be treated as a struct which has one member, an array of structs (each of which is actually the same as `From`).  I'll try that and repost.

Comment: @Daisama - yes that worked - see new code including decode of "likes"

Comment: The original, actual data is just like the example, but it has many of them. So all of them are inside another data[] block. So the file starts like:{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "112...etc

Comment: That will be OK, just define a field for each that is of type `Data` as I did with `likes`. Date and Time may need special handling but give it a go first - eg. I added `DateTime updated_time;` - this converts the input to local time by default

Comment: Alright, thank you very much! I will try to work with what I have so far. May I message you with any additional questions if I run into problems?

Comment: Just add comments here - maybe a different question if it's something complex. I'll be online on and off over the weekend.

Comment: @Zain - I don't know but I cannot think why it would not - this is just a C# class library like any other you could use from the .Net framework

Comment: @Zain - let me know and I will update the answer with appropriate info, good luck

Answer (score 9):

Personally I don't like carrying around dependencies on external libraries when the functionality is provided by the framework. In this case, the [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

var myobj = serializer.Deserialize<MyType>(mystring);
```

Comment: Agreed. Also, I have used the DataContractJsonSerializer class, located in the System.Runtime.Serialization.Json namespace (System.Runtime.Serialization assembly) to deserialized JSon objects:  `DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T)); return (T)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(memoryStream);`

Comment: @Dr.Wily'sApprentice: Which reference or .net framework is needed for that, though? (edit) Ah. `System.ServiceModel.Web` apparently.