# Parsing JSON data in C#

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON data as follows

```
 {"id": "367501354973","from": {
  "name": "Bret Taylor",
  "id": "220439"   }
```

which is returned by an object(result) of IDictionary[String, Object]

***In my C# code:***

I have made a **class for storing the JSON value** which is as follows

```
public class SContent
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string from_name { get; set; }
    public string from_id { get; set; }
}
```

**My main C# function which stores the parses the JSON data and stores the value inside the class properties** is as follows:

```
List<object> data = (List<object>)result["data"];
            foreach (IDictionary<string, object> content in data)
            {
                SContent s = new SContent();

                    s.id = (string)content["id"];
                    s.from_name = (string)content["from.name"];
                    s.from_id = (string)content["from.id"];

            }
```

*When i execute this code, i get an exception saying **System cannot find the Key "from.name" and "from.id"***

When i **comment** the two lines (s.from_name = (string)content["from.name"];s.from_id = (string)content["from.id"];) **my code runs fine.**

**I think i am not able to refer the nested JSON data properly.**

**Can anyone just validate it and please tell me how to refer nested data in JSON in C#?**

**Thanks**

Comment: `content["from"]` likely returns an `IDictionary<string,object>` itself (which is easily verifiable by you :-) which means that, well, you're doing it wrong (by assuming it provides a magical path syntax) .. although, being lazy, I'd just use a DTO-POCO, Json.NET, and a lateral transfer to another type if needing some extreme "normalization".

Comment: try `s.from_name = (string)content["from"].name;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure how you are parsing the JSON string. Are you using a class in the Framework to do the deserialization?

You could use the `JavaScriptSerializer` Class defined in the `System.Web.Script.Serialization` Namespace (you may need to add a reference to System.Web.dll)

Using that class, you would write your code like this:

```
public class SContent
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public SFrom from { get; set; }
}

public class SFrom 
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialization looks like this:

```
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var result = json.Deserialize<SContent>(/*...json text or stream...*/);
```

See [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) on MSDN.  You might also want to check out [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109807/parsing-json-data-with-c-sharp?rq=1).

Comment: And __pst__ is right, Json.NET (http://json.codeplex.com/) is highly reviewed and is considered by many to be one of the best, if not the best, libraries for JSON serialization/deserialization.

Comment: Hey I implemented the above using Dictionary. as pst rightly put it content["from"] returns a Object of Dictionary so i store it in a Dictionary and then take out the value of the same. Thanks for the help everyone!