# How to remove property from json string

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

hi bellow is my JSON string

```
\"Education\":{\"EducationLevel\":[\"\"],\"WithCertification\":[\"CISCO\"]"
```

how can i remove this `" \"EducationLevel\":[\"\"]"` from my string and should get the following JSON string

```
\"Education\":{\"WithCertification\":[\"CISCO\"]"
```

and im using  `string filterString = JsonHelper.JsonSerializer(filters)`

Comment: JSON `""` is not null, nor is `[""]`; `null` is null.

Comment: Don't work on the String, parse the JSON into a C# object, manipulate it there, and serialize back to JSON.

Comment: can you Explain more about it

Answer (score 1):

you can use `yourString.Replace()` function to remove any unwanted `chars` or `strings`

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of json in asp.net.
Here is a msdn link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197957%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

More reading
[Parsing JSON data with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109807/parsing-json-data-with-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

I think what @Thilo means is something like this -

```
        const string Test = "{\"Education\":{\"EducationLevel\":[\"\"],\"WithCertification\":[\"CISCO\"]}}";
        var deserializeObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(Test);
        var other = new { Education = new { EducationLevel = deserializeObject.EducationLevel } };
        var serializeObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(other);
        Console.WriteLine(serializeObject);
```

Note - I am using [JSON.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx)