# Getting the data from a string using JSON using Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, json, vb.net

I need your help: I created a web service that returning me a clean string
after clicking on the url:

```
{
    "PersonID": 125,
    "Title": "Security Officer",
    "Company": "TSA",
    "CellNum": "423-915-3224",
    "EmergencyPhone": "",
    "Email": ""
}
```

How can I extract that string using JSON and get the data??

My WebService:

```
 <OperationContract()>
    <WebGet(ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate:="/getPersonInfo/?personID={personID}&companyCode={companyCode}", BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)>
    Public Function getPersonInfo(ByVal personID As String, ByVal companyCode As String) As Stream
        Dim dba As New DBAccess
        Dim person As New PersonInfo
        Dim m_SelPerson As String = String.Empty
        Dim ds As DataSet = dba.GetPersonInfo(personID, companyCode)
        If Not ds Is Nothing Then
            Dim dr As DataRow = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)
            person = New PersonInfo
            person.PersonID = Convert.ToInt32(dr("PersonID"))
            person.Company = dr("Company")
            person.Title = dr("Title")
            person.CellNum = dr("CellNum")
            person.EmergencyPhone = dr("EmergencyPhone")
            person.Email = dr("Email")
            Dim oSerilzer As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
            m_SelPerson = oSerilzer.Serialize(person)
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        End If
        Return New MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(m_SelPerson))
    End Function
```

JS Function:

```
function getPersonInfo(personID) {
        var json = '"http://122.123.1.118/GSWS/Service1.svc/REST/getPersonInfo/?personid=125&companycode=TSA&sensor=false"';
        obj = JSON.parse(json);
        alert(obj);
    }
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109807/parsing-json-data-with-c-sharp

Comment: .. and surely google will show you vb equivalents if thats what you need

Comment: how can I do it in Javascipt???

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: how can you do what? call the webservice?  did you google that?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<http>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js'></script>
<body>

<script>
    var url = "http://122.123.1.118/GSWS/Service1.svc/REST/getPersonInfo/?personid=125&companycode=TSA&sensor=false";
    $.getJSON( url, function( data ) {
        alert(data.PersonID);
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```