# Writing some sort of nonredundant XML

Tags: c#, file-io, key-value-store

I am currently using the `DataSet.WriteXml` method to rely on the solidness of C#'s classes in order to write files.

My problem is that I would like to write the less redundant information possible.
By default, XML nodes are written like the following:

```
<parameter>VALUE</parameter>
```

But I would rather prefer to write:

```
<parameter="VALUE" />
```

Until now, using the `MappingType.Attribute` I have just been able to format the output like this:

```
<Table1 parameter="VALUE" />
```

But, do you have any trick to get rid of "Table1", here ?

**EDIT:** Or do you have an other class to recommend me to achieve this? I mean, writing my set of keys/values in a proper file...

Comment: `<parameter="VALUE" />` isn't valid XML, so that isn't the option you're after.

Comment: What you mean by redundant here..coz <parameter="VALUE" /> cannot be parsed as XML node

Comment: @DarkKnight - I think by "redundant" OP means repeating "parameter" in `<parameter>VALUE</parameter>`.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed the repeating of "parameter" which is redundant.

Comment: Sadly(?) that's how XML works. It's far from being DRY. I think using attributes (as you already do) is the least "redundant" you can get. But attributes always "belong" to an element. If you need this to transfer data, maybe over the web, then JSON might be an alternative for you.

Comment: Thanks Corak ! I'm going to check JSON.

Comment: Do you just want to export table data (of one table at a time) into a file? Then maybe CSV could be what you're looking for. Or maybe even writing your own binary format, but then you need to be very careful when using that file between different systems.

Comment: Yes, writing my table data in a file is my goal, but I would like to rely on a C# or .net writer/reader class rather than on my own binary system. I looked a bit for JSON but haven't found a class such as JSON.WriteFile(... or something like this.

Comment: Maybe this will help (haven't used it myself): http://stackoverflow.com/a/4109886/1336590

Comment: I finally used `JavaScriptSerializer` to write my file as JSON, it makes my eyes bleed, but it works... Thanks again Corak!

Answer (score 1):

So, In order to avoid redundant data, I switched from XML to JSON, as user Corak suggested me. I ended up with this working code:

```
    private Dictionary<String, String> settingsConfig = new Dictionary<string,string>();

    private const string JSON_SEPARATOR = "\",\"";
    private const string JSON_SEPARATOR_WITH_NEWLINE = "\",\r\n\"";

    private void readConfig()
    {
        if (File.Exists(defaultFilePath))
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer reader = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string fileContents = File.ReadAllText(defaultFilePath);
            fileContents = fileContents.Replace(JSON_SEPARATOR_WITH_NEWLINE, JSON_SEPARATOR);
            settingsConfig = reader.Deserialize<Dictionary<String, String>>(fileContents);
        }
    }

    public void saveConfig()
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer writer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string textToSave = writer.Serialize(settingsConfig);
        textToSave = textToSave.Replace(JSON_SEPARATOR, JSON_SEPARATOR_WITH_NEWLINE);
        File.WriteAllText(defaultFilePath, textToSave);
    }
```

And the written file looks like this:

```
{"parameter0":"VALUE0",
"parameter1":"VALUE1"}
```