# Ajax + webservice + array of object

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, web-services, parsing

I am calling a webservice through ajax call and pass array of object to it after stringify it.

Data after stringifying

```
data = '[{"para1":"pic 1","para2":"drop 1"},{"para1":"pic 2","para2":"drop 2"}]'

 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "path to url/method",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            "data": data
        }),
```

How to receive it and parse in C# webservice.

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string insertroute(string data){
       //how to parse data here
    }
```

Comment: parsing can be done pretty easily with a library: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109807/parsing-json-data-with-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service method will receive the data as a string. You can use the following code to deserialize into a list of objects.

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var result = serializer.Deserialize(mail, typeof(List<object>));
```

As a practice, it would be better if you made a **model** that matches your json object and passed that into the typeof(List<**model**>)

Answer (score 0):

You need to Convert a string to JSON? You can use something like

```
var json = JObject.Parse(data);
```

JObject is from

```
Newtonsoft.Json
```

But, you can just send JSON and deal with JSON and sendback JSON no need to stringify it.

Thanks

Steve